# Android TextWatcher saving batches of similar changes for undo/redo

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, undo, textwatcher

I am trying to make snapshots of an EditText content everytime after a batch of similar changes made to it.

Like for example:

1. when I do several consecutive deletes on consecutive/overlapping text this is a batch and I do a snapshot of the EditText content that results from this
2. when I do several consecutive adds on consecutive/overlapping text this is a batch and I do a snapshot of the EditText content that results from this
3. when I do several consecutive replaces (=modifys) on consecutive/overlapping text this is a batch and I do a snapshot of the EditText content that results from this

I hope you get the idea.

FYI: I need this for an undo/redo mechanism as I do not want/can make a snapshot EVERYTIME the text changes.

How can I achieve my goal?

The code that has failed was written because I though (before trying the code) that the conditions of the toplevel if statements would apply for deleting text / adding text / modifing text.

So how can I change this so that I have a cool text editor-like undo/redo mechanism backend?

```
editBigField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      private static final int NONE = -1;
      private static final int DELETE = 0;
      private static final int ADD = 1;
      private static final int MODIFY = 2;

      private int lastAction = NONE;

      private int delete;

      private int addstart;
      private int addend;

      private int modstart;
      private int modend;

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        if (after == 0) // delete text
        {
          if (lastAction != DELETE || !(start <= delete && start + count - 1 >= delete)) {
            // save state here TODO
            lastAction = DELETE;
          }
          delete = start;
        }
        else if (count == 0 && after > 0) // add text
        {
          if (lastAction != ADD || !(start >= addstart - 1 && start <= addend)) {
            // save state here TODO
            lastAction = ADD;
          }
          addstart = start;
          addend = start + after;
        }
        else if (count != 0 && after > 0) // modify/replace text
        {
          if (lastAction != MODIFY || !(start + count - 1 >= modstart - 1 && start <= modend)) {
            // save state here TODO
            lastAction = MODIFY;
          }
          modstart = start;
          modend = start + after;
        }

      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody need this yet. Undo/redo implementation with batches:

```
public class UndoRedoHelper {
    private static final String TAG = UndoRedoHelper.class.getCanonicalName();
    private boolean mIsUndoOrRedo = false;

    private EditHistory mEditHistory;

    private EditTextChangeListener mChangeListener;

    private TextView mTextView;

    // =================================================================== //

    public UndoRedoHelper(TextView textView) {
        mTextView = textView;
        mEditHistory = new EditHistory();
        mChangeListener = new EditTextChangeListener();
        mTextView.addTextChangedListener(mChangeListener);
    }

    // =================================================================== //

    public void disconnect() {
        mTextView.removeTextChangedListener(mChangeListener);
    }

    public void setMaxHistorySize(int maxHistorySize) {
        mEditHistory.setMaxHistorySize(maxHistorySize);
    }

    public void clearHistory() {
        mEditHistory.clear();
    }

    public boolean getCanUndo() {
        return (mEditHistory.mmPosition > 0);
    }

    public void undo() {
        EditItem edit = mEditHistory.getPrevious();
        if (edit == null) {
            return;
        }

        Editable text = mTextView.getEditableText();
        int start = edit.mmStart;
        int end = start + (edit.mmAfter != null ? edit.mmAfter.length() : 0);

        mIsUndoOrRedo = true;
        text.replace(start, end, edit.mmBefore);
        mIsUndoOrRedo = false;

        for (Object o : text.getSpans(0, text.length(), UnderlineSpan.class)) {
            text.removeSpan(o);
        }

        Selection.setSelection(text, edit.mmBefore == null ? start : (start + edit.mmBefore.length()));
    }

    public boolean getCanRedo() {
        return (mEditHistory.mmPosition < mEditHistory.mmHistory.size());
    }

    public void redo() {
        EditItem edit = mEditHistory.getNext();
        if (edit == null) {
            return;
        }

        Editable text = mTextView.getEditableText();
        int start = edit.mmStart;
        int end = start + (edit.mmBefore != null ? edit.mmBefore.length() : 0);

        mIsUndoOrRedo = true;
        text.replace(start, end, edit.mmAfter);
        mIsUndoOrRedo = false;

        // This will get rid of underlines inserted when editor tries to come
        // up with a suggestion.
        for (Object o : text.getSpans(0, text.length(), UnderlineSpan.class)) {
            text.removeSpan(o);
        }

        Selection.setSelection(text, edit.mmAfter == null ? start
                : (start + edit.mmAfter.length()));
    }

    public void storePersistentState(Editor editor, String prefix) {
        // Store hash code of text in the editor so that we can check if the
        // editor contents has changed.
        editor.putString(prefix + ".hash",
                String.valueOf(mTextView.getText().toString().hashCode()));
        editor.putInt(prefix + ".maxSize", mEditHistory.mmMaxHistorySize);
        editor.putInt(prefix + ".position", mEditHistory.mmPosition);
        editor.putInt(prefix + ".size", mEditHistory.mmHistory.size());

        int i = 0;
        for (EditItem ei : mEditHistory.mmHistory) {
            String pre = prefix + "." + i;

            editor.putInt(pre + ".start", ei.mmStart);
            editor.putString(pre + ".before", ei.mmBefore.toString());
            editor.putString(pre + ".after", ei.mmAfter.toString());

            i++;
        }
    }

    public boolean restorePersistentState(SharedPreferences sp, String prefix)
            throws IllegalStateException {

        boolean ok = doRestorePersistentState(sp, prefix);
        if (!ok) {
            mEditHistory.clear();
        }

        return ok;
    }

    private boolean doRestorePersistentState(SharedPreferences sp, String prefix) {
        String hash = sp.getString(prefix + ".hash", null);
        if (hash == null) {
            // No state to be restored.
            return true;
        }

        if (Integer.valueOf(hash) != mTextView.getText().toString().hashCode()) {
            return false;
        }

        mEditHistory.clear();
        mEditHistory.mmMaxHistorySize = sp.getInt(prefix + ".maxSize", -1);

        int count = sp.getInt(prefix + ".size", -1);
        if (count == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String pre = prefix + "." + i;

            int start = sp.getInt(pre + ".start", -1);
            String before = sp.getString(pre + ".before", null);
            String after = sp.getString(pre + ".after", null);

            if (start == -1 || before == null || after == null) {
                return false;
            }
            mEditHistory.add(new EditItem(start, before, after));
        }

        mEditHistory.mmPosition = sp.getInt(prefix + ".position", -1);
        if (mEditHistory.mmPosition == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // =================================================================== //

    private final class EditHistory {
        private int mmPosition = 0;
        private int mmMaxHistorySize = -1;

        private final LinkedList<EditItem> mmHistory = new LinkedList<EditItem>();

        private void clear() {
            mmPosition = 0;
            mmHistory.clear();
        }

        private void add(EditItem item) {
            while (mmHistory.size() > mmPosition) {
                mmHistory.removeLast();
            }
            mmHistory.add(item);
            mmPosition++;

            if (mmMaxHistorySize >= 0) {
                trimHistory();
            }
        }

        private void setMaxHistorySize(int maxHistorySize) {
            mmMaxHistorySize = maxHistorySize;
            if (mmMaxHistorySize >= 0) {
                trimHistory();
            }
        }

        private void trimHistory() {
            while (mmHistory.size() > mmMaxHistorySize) {
                mmHistory.removeFirst();
                mmPosition--;
            }

            if (mmPosition < 0) {
                mmPosition = 0;
            }
        }

        private EditItem getCurrent() {
            if (mmPosition == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            return mmHistory.get(mmPosition - 1);
        }

        private EditItem getPrevious() {
            if (mmPosition == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            mmPosition--;
            return mmHistory.get(mmPosition);
        }

        private EditItem getNext() {
            if (mmPosition >= mmHistory.size()) {
                return null;
            }

            EditItem item = mmHistory.get(mmPosition);
            mmPosition++;
            return item;
        }
    }

    private final class EditItem {
        private int mmStart;
        private CharSequence mmBefore;
        private CharSequence mmAfter;

        public EditItem(int start, CharSequence before, CharSequence after) {
            mmStart = start;
            mmBefore = before;
            mmAfter = after;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EditItem{" +
                    "mmStart=" + mmStart +
                    ", mmBefore=" + mmBefore +
                    ", mmAfter=" + mmAfter +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    enum ActionType {
        INSERT, DELETE, PASTE, NOT_DEF;
    }

    private final class EditTextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {
        private CharSequence mBeforeChange;
        private CharSequence mAfterChange;
        private ActionType lastActionType = ActionType.NOT_DEF;
        private long lastActionTime = 0;

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            if (mIsUndoOrRedo) {
                return;
            }

            mBeforeChange = s.subSequence(start, start + count);
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (mIsUndoOrRedo) {
                return;
            }

            mAfterChange = s.subSequence(start, start + count);
            makeBatch(start);
        }

        private void makeBatch(int start) {
            ActionType at = getActionType();
            EditItem editItem = mEditHistory.getCurrent();
            if ((lastActionType != at || ActionType.PASTE == at || System.currentTimeMillis() - lastActionTime > 1000) || editItem == null) {
                mEditHistory.add(new EditItem(start, mBeforeChange, mAfterChange));
            } else {
                if (at == ActionType.DELETE) {
                    editItem.mmStart = start;
                    editItem.mmBefore = TextUtils.concat(mBeforeChange, editItem.mmBefore);
                } else {
                    editItem.mmAfter = TextUtils.concat(editItem.mmAfter, mAfterChange);
                }
            }
            lastActionType = at;
            lastActionTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        private ActionType getActionType() {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mBeforeChange) && TextUtils.isEmpty(mAfterChange)) {
                return ActionType.DELETE;
            } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mBeforeChange) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(mAfterChange)) {
                return ActionType.INSERT;
            } else {
                return ActionType.PASTE;
            }
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    }
}
```